# Calling a JavaScript function from flash movie controls

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-2

I have a swf streaming an flv with the default controls from Flash. Is there a way to call a javascript function when the pause button is clicked? And then another when the play button is clicked?

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Added the `actionscript-2` tag to your question. It's nice to lock people who are willing to answer down to a specific language as this will yield you more accurate answers :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An easy way is on the  button controls simply call

```
getURL("javascript:yourFunction();");
```

Comment: This will only work with AS2, `getURL` is not present in AS3.

Comment: Still giving this a +1 as the question doesn't specify which ActionScript version is to be used.

Comment: Thanks shanethehat. That's what I needed, and it was AS2.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the `getURL` technique will interupt and halt any JavaScript already executing on the page. That said, it is the easier solution to implement if there is no danger of overwriting.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is using [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html).  Here's an example:

AS:

```
ExternalInterface.call("pauseFunction");
```

JS:

```
function pauseFunction() {
    alert("Called from ActionScript");
}
```

Comment: I've never been able to get this working. Do you need to use [`addCallback()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#addCallback()) and some other stuff beforehand?

Comment: No, addCallback is for when you want to call an AS function from Javascript.  The most common cause of this not working is script access being denied on the HTML object.

Answer (score 0):

1. Import the ExternalInterface library to your action script by using the line:

   ```
   import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
   ```

   **Note:** without this line you will not be able to call the JavaScript function.
2. Use this command to call the JavaScript function:

   ```
   ExternalInterface.call("pauseFunc", "");
   ```
3. In your HTML page, add your JavaScript function:

   ```
   <script>
   function pauseFunc() {
      doSomthing ...
   }
   </script>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

use this Action code:

```js
getURL("javascript:ActionJS()");
```

ActionJS is function on html file

read more => [Call Js from Flash file](http://www.obinb.com/2015/10/huong-dan-goi-ham-javascript-tu-trong.html)