# communicate from flash to jquery - jquery scroll path Vs flash buttons

Tags: jquery, actionscript

I'm using a jquery scroll path in the link below.

[jquery scroll path](http://joelb.me/scrollpath/)

Few buttons in the below of the screen to control the scrolling. Instead of those buttons I would like to use few buttons developed in flash. But the click events are not working and unable to communicate from flash to jquery.

Any help on this really helpful.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You can define the js function to be called as you would usually, and call that from actionscript.

If you are using as2, then you could do something like:

```
getURL('javascript:doTheScrollingForMe();');
```

That's what I use generally. Otherwise, there are similar questions on SO about this subject, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8129016/calling-a-javascript-function-from-flash-movie-controls) and [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426069/as2-best-crossbrowser-way-of-calling-javascript-functions). There's [this](http://www.slideshare.net/BeautifulInterfaces/connecting-flash-and-javascript-using-externalinterface-2452543) also.

The javascript code you are using with your buttons should not change (most probably).

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) class in ActionScript 3.
It's actually very simple, using the following code;

#### ActionScript 3

```
// Import
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

// Call the javascript function
ExternalInterface.call( "myFunction", "Hello there!" );
```

#### JavaScript

```
function myFunction( message )
{
    window.alert( message );
}
```

The Flash object calls the javascript function `myFunction`, and an alert with the message `Hello there!` appears in your browser.

---

Simply firing a `javascript:myFunction( "Hello there!" )` call is not reccomended (at least in AS3) because some browsers might think it's insecure and make things difficult. Using `ExternalInterface` is the preferred method. You can also use it to call ActionScript functions in JavaScript, but that's behind the scope of your question.